# Have we seen any references to Gotrek and / or Felix since the Age of Sigmar began?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy, age-of-sigmar

During The End Times, Gotrek:

> ascended to Godhood

and Felix

> died, like absolutely everyone else

I’ve not read much of the [Age Of Sigmar](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Warhammer:_Age_of_Sigmar), I just can’t bring myself to invest any time in it.

But can anyone tell me if there has been any mention of either Gotrek or Felix since the Age of Sigmar began?

Comment: Which book is this from? I haven't read any past the original 6, but it would be interesting to read.

Comment: @DarkHippo [Kinslayer](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21411989-kinslayer)

Comment: @DarkHippo I've read them all it's far and away the very worst Gotrek and Felix book. The author really butchers them. Characters have completely changed. Everything is boring and bleak and horrible. I'd recommend reading a synopsis of it to avoid actually reading the book itself.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll probably give it a look, cheers (I mean the synopsis, not the book)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gotrek is back!

It seems that Gotrek is again a mortal dwarf within the Age of Sigmar in the "[Realmslayer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1784967866)" book:

> Gotrek Gurnisson was the greatest monster slayer of the age, who met his doom at the End Times. The heroic duardin stepped forth into the Realm of Chaos to fight the daemons gnawing at the world's ending and satisfy his death oath, leaving behind his companion Felix Jaeger. Now Gotrek has returned, having outlived the old gods and the Old World. Spat from the ruinous depths with his redemption unfulfilled, he emerges into the Mortal Realms, a strange new world where gods walk the earth and dark forces are ascendant. Nothing is as he remembers. His oaths are dust, and the lands are torn asunder by Chaos. Yet when Gotrek learns of human champions being elevated to immortality for Sigmar’s fight against this darkness, the so-called 'Stormcast Eternals', he knows why fate has brought him into this new age. To find Felix. For only then can he find the peace in death he seeks. But is there more to Gotrek's apotheosis than even he can fathom? Has he truly been chosen by Grimnir and for what purpose?

Answer (score 2):

### Probably not

I checked as many the Age of Sigmar books as I could acquire, and I can’t find any reference to Gotrek or Felix *by name*.

However, we do have a bit of likely information about Gotrek. At the end of the End Times, as noted in the question, Gotrek took on the role of Grimnir. As such, it’s likely that any references to Grimnir in Age of Sigmar works refer, in reality, to Gotrek. According to the sourcebook transcript [here](http://www.heresy-online.net/forums/338-age-sigmar/191514-age-sigmar-lore.html):

> While exploring the Realm of Chamon Sigmar found the Duardin Gods
> Grungni and Grimnir imprisoned at the top of the Iron Mountains. How
> they came to be there, they would not say, but each readily swore the
> oath of allegience and set about repaying their debt to Sigmar.
> Grungni, now crippled in form and unable to raise his hammer and fight
> alongside his brother-god, promised to fabricate whatever Sigmar
> desired as his smithing skills were unharmed. Grungni gathered the
> remaining Duardin and established the Iron Karak, a bastion of the
> Steamhead Duardin that would always answer Sigmars call. However
> Grimnir was a warrior and asked Sigmar to name an enemy worthy of his
> axes and that it would die, Sigmar named Vulcatrix the Mother of
> Salamanders that terrorized the Realm of Aqshy. Though the battle was
> titanic and created the Plains of Aqshy by its very occurence, the
> end result was that both the Slayer God and the Ur-Salamander
> destroyed each other. Where the hot coal remnants of Vulcatrix landed
> a new volcano was born, but where Grimnir’s fragments ended up is a
> mystery that the Duardian share with no one.

Those fragments of Grimnir/Gotrek are ur-gold, which the duardin (dwarves) seek to reforge someday into Grimnir.

> ‘Ur-gold is what Grimnir left us of his power and will,’ said Rolk,
> staring into the complex geometry of the rune in his palm, his hard
> face appearing to express something like veneration in the shifting
> light of the flame. ‘By harnessing its might we do him glory in the
> manner in which he approves.’
>
> <sub>*Age of Sigmar: Warbeast*</sub>

Of course, there remains the possibility that the Grimnir referred to here is the original Grimnir, not Gotrek-as-Grimnir. If that is the case, we don’t know anything about Gortrek’s fate, save perhaps that he continues to fight eternally in the Realm of Chaos.

Comment: I'll accept this answer before the bounty expires in three days, I just want to wait and see if anyone comes up with anything else before then.